# active record failing at save user

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, auto-increment, camping

I am trying to implement an authentication system on a Camping app and I made significant changes to the User model to incorporate this, but now my post method wont auto assign and auto_incrememnt user_ids to my User class.

I am trying to use the these tutorials:
http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/
http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-ii/

I am not using views at the moment, I am sending HTTParty posts to create users, but the response comes back with the id as null and the record is not saving to the DB:

```
resp = "{\"id\":null,\"username\":\"testusername\",\"email\":null,\"encrypted_password\":null,\"salt\":null,\"password\":\"testpassword\",\"name\":\"testname\",\"github_login\":\"testgithub\",\"created_at\":null,\"updated_at\":null}"
```

Can anyone assist with this issue or get me on the right track? thank you!

(Apologies for posting so much code, I am new to activerecord/camping and dont know where my mistake might be.)

heres my models:

```
module Notepasser
  include Camping::Session
end

module Notepasser::Models

  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
    include BCrypt
    attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

    has_many :sent_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    has_many :received_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => 'recipient_id'  
    validates :username, 
              :presence => true,
              :uniqueness => true, 
              :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, 
              :presence => true, 
              :uniqueness => true, 
              :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates :password, :confirmation => true
    validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
    before_save :encrypt_password
    after_save :clear_password

    def encrypt_password
      if !password.empty?
        self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
        self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
      end
    end

    def clear_password
      self.password = nil
    end

    def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
      if  EMAIL_REGEX.match(username_or_email)    
        user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
      else
        user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
      end
      if user && user.match_password(login_password)
        return user
      else
        return false
      end
    end

    def match_password(login_password="")
      encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
    end
  end

  class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User'
  end
end
```

Here is the controller I am having issues with, the user_id is not being generated automatically and when pry into post and call @current_user.save, it returns false, which makes me think I am failing a validation on the User's model but I just do not know where.

```
module Notepasser::Controllers
  class Users < R '/users'
    attr_reader :current_user

    #new user
    def post
      username ||= @input.username
      password ||= @input.password
      name     ||= @input.name
      github   ||= @input.github_login
      @current_user = Notepasser::Models::User.new(username: username, 
                                                   password: password, 
                                                   name: name,
                                                   github_login: github) 
      @current_user ? @status = 200 : @status = 400
      @current_user.save
      @current_user.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a huge code dump. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example so others don't have to wade through all your code to help you.

Comment: @ptd thanks for the feedback, is that better?

Comment: try `@current_user.errors.full_messages`

Comment: The `email` is required to successfully validate, but it doesn't look like you are sending an email. See your `User` model with `validates email, presence: true` etc.

Comment: @Zabba and ptd, thank you for your assistance, I did eventually figure out that it was the email in this sitaution. the `@current_user.errors.full_messages` made this very clear,  I will write an answer, but if you want to add that little tid bit, ill upvote you, thanks again.